# Map Fragment Inflation Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

While I initially setup map in fragment activity it gives an error I do not understand, I check the XML for proper name but it gives me an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.volxom.nearbyalerts.activities.MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Can you post your XML

Comment: yes sure im on it

Comment: @MuhammadAli Show your xml .

Comment: sir here it is iv edit the post

Comment: if i use <Fragment> instead of <fragment> from capital latter it give and erroe

Comment: use `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" ` instead of `android:name="com.volxom.nearbyalerts.activities.MainActivity"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `SupportMapFragment` in name attribute.

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Your XML should be like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You should have this in your manifest:

```
<application>    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: same problem @Bhuvanesh Bs

Comment: again same problem

Comment: @MuhammadAli try with `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: do you have the updated your API key in your Manifest

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in my answer. Now I updated. Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: only class . not `android:class`

Comment: Oops. Editing in mobile. So much mistake I'm making. Thanks again @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @MuhammadAli Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE then run .

Comment: haha.....@BhuvaneshBs really i forgot to insert API key.......i did work On Map's API long time ago......haha...it worked Thanks IntelliJAmiya and BhuvaneshBs

Comment: @MuhammadAli sloppy mistake costs you !

Comment: Thanks@IntelliJAmiya Bhai